# Set of points making derivative matrix nonsingular is open

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove that if $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is continuously differentiable, the set of points for which $\nabla F$ is nonsingular is open. I want to write the set $\{(x,y)\mid\det \nabla F\neq 0\}$ as the preimage of an open set under a continuous function.

Can I define a function $G:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $$G(x,y)=\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial x}(x,y)\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial y}(x,y)-\frac{\partial F_1}{\partial y}(x,y)\frac{\partial F_2}{\partial x}(x,y)$$ and then $G^{-1}(\mathbb{R}-\{0\})=\{(x,y) \mid \det \nabla F \neq 0\}$?

Comment: What you did is fine for the 2-dimensional case, but the same reasoning works in general: $\det$ is a continuous function (it's even a polynomial in the entries of a matrix), $\nabla F$ is continuous because $F$ is assumed to be continuously differentiable. So, the composition $\det \nabla F$ is continuous. So, the preimage of the open set $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is open.